# Accessing Resource ID in GCP without gcloud

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-cloud-iam, google-cloud-monitoring

I want to get resource ids of resources in google cloud platform.

I have enough access to google cloud console to access those resources.

However I can't access through gcloud shell utility and need additional permissions.

```
$ gcloud alpha monitoring policies list --project kbc-env --filter="userLabels.alerting_db_type:*" --format json  > ~/Downloads/kbc-env.json

ERROR: (gcloud.alpha.monitoring.policies.list) User [sjain@kbc.com] does not have permission to access projects instance [kbc-env] (or it may not exist): Caller does not have required permission to use project kbc-env. Grant the caller the roles/serviceusage.serviceUsageConsumer role, or a custom role with the serviceusage.services.use permission, by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=kbc-env and then retry. Propagation of the new permission may take a few minutes.
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.Help
  links:
  - description: Google developer console IAM admin
    url: https://console.developers.google.com/iam-admin/iam/project?project=kbc-env
- '@type': type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo
  domain: googleapis.com
  metadata:
    consumer: projects/kbc-env
    service: monitoring.googleapis.com
  reason: USER_PROJECT_DENIED
```

How can i get resource ids without gcloud permissions ?

Answer (score 0):

### To get resource id without gcloud

#### Step 1 :

Go to GCP console and open the resource directly

For e.g. You can go to Cloud Monitoring then click on Alerting and then click to one of alerts.

#### Step 2 :

We can get resource id from the URL like shown on the screenshot
[image]